# How to reconcile differences in merging to different staging branches from a branch in a fork?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-fork

I am dealing with 2 branches that are meant for staging, let me call them `A` and `B` respectively, with `A` being higher & closer to production.

I have a fork of the repo and I have my own branch `X` that begins from `A` because it is the higher stage. I have a fork because I don't have write access to the repository.

Now, the `B` branch had `A` merged into it for consistency but has since accumulated commits `CB1` and `CB2` from other people. I wanted to merge my branch `X` from my fork into `B` and ran into merge conflicts, which I resolved with a new commit. My merge was successful after resolving merge conflicts.

However, when I create a pull request against branch `A`, I have modifications that shouldn't be in `A`, changes made by other people into branch `B`. How can I reconcile this? Can this even be done?

Comment: _"A being higher"_ what do you mean?

Comment: Stages are `dev`, `alpha`, `beta`, `prod`. If we use `dev` for `B`, `A` could be any of the others.